# count total items in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, count

How can I count the total items in this array below?

```
Array
(
    [upload] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1024x768.jpg
                    [1] => 1280x800.jpg
                    [2] => 1280x1024.jpg
                    [3] => 1440x900.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => image/jpeg
                    [3] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\wamp\tmp\php34FE.tmp
                    [1] => C:\wamp\tmp\php353D.tmp
                    [2] => C:\wamp\tmp\php356D.tmp
                    [3] => C:\wamp\tmp\php35AC.tmp
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 469159
                    [1] => 602230
                    [2] => 739779
                    [3] => 707039
                )

        )

)
```

this is my method, but I think it's stupid! any better ways/ methods to count the total items inside the array?

```
<pre>
<?php if ($_FILES) {print_r($_FILES);}?>
</pre>

<?php 
echo count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

if(empty($_FILES['upload']['name'][0]))
{
    echo '0 file has been uploaded.';
}
?>
```

many thanks,
Lau

Comment: What's stupid about 'count();' ?

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong here. This is exactly the right way to count the elements.

Comment: lol probably i had made it too complicated! just it might have another better way... :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is certainly not stupid. If you want to count the number of uploads that occurred without error, you could `foreach` through `$_FILES['upload']['error']` to ensure they're all `0`.

Comment: Edit = Typo.  Checking for actual errors is a great idea here.

Comment: @Charles: Thanks for the grammar fix.

Answer (score 1):

FYI... the $_FILES array structure will change if you have a form element that is nested.

eg.

```
<input name="mysuperform[image_file]" type="file" />
```

Try it and see... also try:

```
<input name="mysuperform[images][image_file]" type="file" />
```

Good luck.